# How to enable Mermaid on Self Hosted Gitea?

Tags: markdown, readme, mermaid, gitea

I have Mermaid working on GitHub and would like the same on Gitea. I have some mermaid markdown code that I want to put in the readme.md file, but it's not working on Gitea. I assume because it's not enabled yet.

So I assume I will need to install or enable mermaid somehow, but I can't find any easy tutorials or guides that tells me from beginning to end on how to install mermaid for Gitea.

My Gitea is installed and hosted on a Windows Server that I can access via RDP.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Looks like it should "just work". What version of Gitea are you using? Can you provide a sample snippet that isn't working?